# Explain what for (char c : str) does?

Tags: c++

I am asking since I couldnt immediately find an answer on google, I know the answer is simple.

what does for `(char c : str) {}` do in a for loop?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for

Comment: This is called a range for loop.

Comment: That is C++ not C which is a different language.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  It it they will go over the modern changes to C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It iterates the individual characters of `str`, copying each one to the (local) variable `c` for use in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Based on assumptions, that's indeed what [happens](https://cppinsights.io/lnk?code=I2luY2x1ZGUgPHN0cmluZz4KI2luY2x1ZGUgPGlvc3RyZWFtPgoKaW50IG1haW4oKQp7CiAgc3RkOjpzdHJpbmcgc3RyeyJIZWxsbywgd29ybGQhIn07CiAgZm9yKGNoYXIgYyA6IHN0ciApewogICAgc3RkOjpjb3V0IDw8IGMgPDwgc3RkOjplbmRsOwogIH0KfQ==&insightsOptions=cpp17&std=cpp17&rev=1.0). Which doesn't mean that a whole boat load of other things could happen.